# mysql escaping single and double quotes

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a script that i am writing to move certain fields to a new db like

```
$results = mysql_query ( "SELECT body, title  FROM $source_db.Post" );
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
if(mysql_num_rows($users_result) > 0){
    $insert = "INSERT INTO wp_posts (`body`,`title`) VALUES ('{$row['body']}', '{$row['row']}')";
    mysql_query($insert);
    }
}
```

but as you can see the query will break everytime due to the single and double quotes, is there a solution to this problem like herdok or something

```
INSERT INTO wp_posts (`body`,`title`)
            VALUES
                ('Here are the final returns from today's ...<br /><br />he stayed home...<br />
<div class="entry-content">
<div class="entry-body">', 'something')
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string` is made for just this.

[PHP: mysql_real_escape_string](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO wp_posts ('body','title') VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($row['body'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($row['row'])."')";
```

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to use mysqli and prepared statements

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("insert into table (id,name,longstring) values (?,?,?));
$stmt->bind_param('iss',$row["id"],$row["name"],$row["body"]);
$stmt->execute();
```

mysqli will bind the assigned parameters to the ? in the prepared statement as an integer (i) or a string (s).

Answer (score 0):

The sanest approach is to use bound parameters. [Bobby Tables has examples](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).