# PHP MySql MsSql How to Insert or Update a ['] or ["] or [`] Char?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, vb.net

Is there anyway to insert values like  **'** or **"** or **`** into Mysql or MsSql via php and VB.NET?

It always return an error. Sometimes we must insert these character.
In the Phpmyadmin, it can inserts/updated with successfull. But how?

Please help, i am newbie. I cannot search it in MySql/MsSql Dev pages.
Thanks

Comment: Prepared statements or escaping. Prepared statements are the route you should go.

Comment: Thanks for Mr. @chris85.

I get an answer here : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763514/mysql-escaping-single-and-double-quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a \ (backslash) in front of the quotes and you should be good to go.

In PHP use the query like this to use [mysql QUOTE()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-quote-function.php)

```
 <?php $query = "
        INSERT INTO
            `mytable`
        SET
            `mycolumn` = QUOTE($myphpvariable)";
 ?>
```

Or you could use [addslashes()](http://php.net/addslashes) in PHP.

```
$myvariable = addslashes($myvariable);
```

But what you should **REALLY** do is use

> [Prepared Statements.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: But i am insert from php.

Comment: @AnggaLisdiyanto I have updated my answer.  If you find my answer helpful can you click the up arrow next to it,  and if you find it to be the answer that solved your question, can you click the check mark to indicate it is a correct answer.  Thanks.  :)